# Verify Eigenpairs

Tags: code-golf, math, matrix, linear-algebra

In this challenge, you will be given a square matrix `A`, a vector `v`, and a scalar `λ`. You will be required to determine if `(λ, v)` is an eigenpair corresponding to `A`; that is, whether or not `Av = λv`.

## Dot Product

The dot product of two vectors is the sum of element-wise multiplication. For example, the dot product of the following two vectors is:

```
(1, 2, 3) * (4, 5, 6) = 1*4 + 2*5 + 3*6 = 32
```

Note that the dot product is only defined between two vectors of the same length.

## Matrix-Vector Multiplication

A matrix is a 2D grid of values. An `m` x `n` matrix has `m` rows and `n` columns. We can imagine an `m` x `n` matrix as `m` vectors of length `n` (if we take the rows).

Matrix-Vector multiplication is defined between an `m` x `n` matrix and a size-`n` vector. If we multiply an `m` x `n` matrix and a size-`n` vector, we obtain a size-`m` vector. The `i`-th value in the result vector is the dot product of the `i`-th row of the matrix and the original vector.

#### Example

```
        1 2 3 4 5
Let A = 3 4 5 6 7
        5 6 7 8 9

        1
        3
Let v = 5
        7
        9
```

If we multiply the matrix and the vector `Av = x`, we get the following:

x<sub>1</sub> = A<sup>T</sup><sub>1</sub> * v `/* AT1 means the first row of A; A1 would be the first column */` = (1,2,3,4,5) * (1,3,5,7,9) = 1*1 + 2*3 + 3*5 + 4*7 + 5*9 = 1+6+15+28+45 = 95

x<sub>2</sub> = A<sup>T</sup><sub>2</sub> * v = (3,4,5,6,7) * (1,3,5,7,9) = 3*1 + 4*3 + 5*5 + 6*7 + 7*9 = 3+12+25+42+63 = 145

x<sub>3</sub> = A<sup>T</sup><sub>3</sub> * v = (5,6,7,8,9) * (1,3,5,7,9) = 5*1 + 6*3 + 7*5 + 8*7 + 9*9 = 5+18+35+56+81 = 195

So, we get `Av = x = (95, 145, 195)`.

## Scalar Multiplication

Multiplication of a scalar (a single number) and a vector is simply element-wise multiplication. For example, `3 * (1, 2, 3) = (3, 6, 9)`. It's fairly straightforward.

## Eigenvalues and Eigenvectors

Given the matrix `A`, we say that `λ` is an eigenvalue corresponding to `v` and `v` is an eigenvector corresponding to `λ` **if and only if** `Av = λv`. (Where `Av` is matrix-vector multiplication and `λv` is scalar multiplication).

`(λ, v)` is an eigenpair.

## Challenge Specifications

#### Input

Input will consist of a matrix, a vector, and a scalar. These can be taken in any order in any reasonable format.

#### Output

Output will be a truthy/falsy value; truthy if and only if the scalar and the vector are an eigenpair with the matrix specified.

## Rules

- Standard loopholes apply
- If a built-in for verifying an eigenpair exists in your language, you may not use it.
- You may assume that all numbers are integers

## Test Cases

```
 MATRIX  VECTOR  EIGENVALUE
 2 -3 -1    3
 1 -2 -1    1    1    ->    TRUE
 1 -3  0    0

 2 -3 -1    1
 1 -2 -1    1    -2   ->    TRUE
 1 -3  0    1

 1  6  3    1
 0 -2  0    0    4    ->    TRUE
 3  6  1    1

 1  0 -1    2
-1  1  1    1    7    ->    FALSE
 1  0  0    0

-4 3    1    
 2 1    2    2    ->    TRUE

2    1    2    ->    TRUE
```

I will add a 4x4 later.

[Unreadable Test Cases that are easier for testing](https://hastebin.com/niqinazizu.lua)

Comment: [Related.](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/44926/8478)

Comment: @MartinEnder Thanks. I originally had a similar challenge for arbitrary sized matrices where you were meant to calculate a basis for each unique eigenspace but that's in the sandbox still because it seems too confusing.

Comment: If inputs can have have other dimensions than 3x3, you should cover some of that in your test cases.

Comment: Also while the test case format is very readable, it's a pain to copy, because (just looking at a byte stream) the three arguments are all interleaved.

Comment: @MartinEnder Alright, I'll add a 2x2 and 4x4 test test case and link to a pastebin with more (un)readable(?) I/O.

Comment: So can we assume that the input is at least 2x2? Can it be 1x1?

Comment: I looked through this question and understood *less* about it afterwards :)

Comment: @ThisGuy Eigensystems are probably *just* on the other side of what you can reasonably *learn* from the specification of a PPCG challenge if you're not familiar with it beforehand. It's not a terribly difficult concept though, so if you read up on it on Wikipedia or some other online resources, the challenge should be clear quite quickly.

Comment: @ThisGuy Don't worry, it took me a few months to get up to this point. The core of the challenge is really just checking if a matrix times a vector is the same as a number times that vector.

Comment: @MartinEnder No, I'll add a 1x1.

Comment: @user00001 If you need help, *eigenpair-aphrase* it for you. :P

Answer (score 11, accepted):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 5 bytes

```
æ.⁵⁼×
```

This is a triadic, full program.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/jelly#@394md6jxq2PGvccnv7///9oQx0FEIr9r2v0PzpawUhHQdcYiA1jdbgUokFSukaoXKCsgkFsLAA)

#### How it works

```
æ.⁵⁼×  Main link
       Left argument:  v (eigenvector)
       Right argument: λ (eigenvalue)
       Third argument: A (matrix)

  ⁵    Third; yield A.
æ.     Take the dot product of v and A, yielding Av.
    ×  Multiply v and λ component by component, yielding λv.
   ⁼   Test the results to the left and to the right for equality.
```

Comment: >_> this is too short :P Nice answer

Comment: That's crazy talk! :P

Comment: You write something, and think "nothing could be shorter!". Then MATL comes along and halves your code size. Then Jelly comes along and halves that >_>

Comment: @HyperNeutrino Don't compare apples to oranges. Golfing languages have as little as one byte per operation, something normal languages rarely have. The spec has three operations (two multiplications and an equality), and allowing for an extra byte to duplicate `v` one could expect as little as four bytes.

Comment: I like how both Jelly and MATL use two bytes for matrix multiplication, which means that this answer really shows how good Jelly is at taking input, all else being equal.

Answer (score 13):

### Mathematica, 10 bytes

```
#2.#==#3#&
```

Takes input like `{vector, matrix, scalar}` and returns a boolean.

Comment: >_> this was too easy for Mathematica. +1 :P

Comment: @HyperNeutrino And now we wait for MATL...

Comment: Well MATL has appeared >_>

Comment: One of those moments when you think nothing can be shorter and MATL pops up suddenly :)

Comment: @Mr.Xcoder And then Jelly shows up.

Comment: Suppose we're waiting for 05AB1E now @Steadybox

Answer (score 11):

## MATL, 7 bytes

```
*i2GY*=
```

Inputs in order: `l`,`v`,`A`.

Explanation:

```
*  % implicitly get l and v, multiply.
i  % get A
2G % get second input, i.e., v again
Y* % perform matrix multiplication
=  % test equality of both multiplications
```

Surprisingly long answer, if you ask me, mostly because I needed a way to get all the input correctly. I do not think that less than 5 bytes is possible, but it would be cool if someone found a 5 or 6 byte solution.

Basically, this calculates `l*v==A*v`.

Comment: "Surprisingly long" I was expecting at least 20 bytes >_> nice answer though :P

Comment: Well, considering that the MATLAB answer would come in at 16 bytes `@(A,v,l)A*v==v*l`, this seems quite verbose, and I have a feeling 6 should be plenty if I get the input somewhat smarter.

Comment: Apparently it came in at 38 bytes but I'm pretty sure it can be golfed down.

Comment: @HyperNeutrino Added my own to make the previous comment true. (or truthy...?)

Answer (score 6):

## [CJam](https://sourceforge.net/p/cjam), 15 bytes

```
q~W$f.*::+@@f*=
```

Takes input in the form `vector scalar matrix`.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/cjam#@19YF66SpqdlZaXt4JCmZfv/f7ShAhDGKugaKURHGynoGivoGsYCBYF8KMNYQcEgNhYA)

**Explanation**

```
q~               e# Read and eval the input
  W$             e# Copy the bottom most value (the vector)
    f.*::+       e# Perform element-wise multiplication with each row of the matrix, then
                 e#   sum the results of each (ie dot product with each row) 
          @@     e# Move the resulting vector to the bottom of the stack
            f*   e# Element-wise multiplication of the scalar and the vector
              =  e# Check if the two vectors are equal
```

Answer (score 5):

## MATLAB, 16 bytes

```
@(A,v,l)A*v==v*l
```

Rather trivial answer. Defines an anonymous function taking the inputs, and calculates element-wise equality of the resulting vectors. A single zero in a logical array makes an array falsey in MATLAB.

Comment: Wasn't aware of the falseyness of e.g. `[true,false]`, thanks for teaching me=)

Comment: @flawr See [this](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/95057/32352) answer by Suever (which is also applicable to MATLAB). Basically, an almost-but-not-quite (empty matrix `[]` is different) implicit `all()` is called on the input of `if`, `while` etc.

Answer (score 2):

## MATLAB, 38 bytes

```
function r=f(m,v,s);r=isequal(m*v,s*v)
```

Returns 1 or 0.

## MATLAB, 30 bytes

```
function r=f(m,v,s);r=m*v==s*v
```

Returns

```
1
1
1
```

as a truthy value. A falsy value is a similar vector with any or all values 0 instead of 1.

Comment: I don't know MATLAB, but can the `isequal` function be shortened to `==`?

Comment: @HyperNeutrino `isequal` would be needed if the output required `true` or `false` rather than a truthy or falsey value. As the challenge stands, `==` is indeed enough.

Comment: @HyperNeutrino It would return a vector containing the results of elementwise comparison of the two vectors.

Comment: Oh okay. Nice answer though!

Comment: wouldn't an annonymous function be shorter?

Answer (score 2):

## C++, <s>225</s> 203 bytes

*Thanks to @Cort Ammon and @Julian Wolf for saving 22 bytes!*

```
#import<vector>
#define F(v,i)for(i=0;i<v.size();++i)
using V=std::vector<float>;int f(std::vector<V>m,V v,float s){V p;int i,j;F(m,i){p.push_back(0);F(v,j)p[i]+=v[j]*m[i][j];}F(v,i)v[i]*=s;return v==p;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/cpp-gcc#jY/BbsIwDIbvfYoILgkE1Ba0SaTtkUfohaGpK@kWRtOqSXNY1GdnTlo2bhDJsuP8/vznOhd123Q6MbzUTZcF8xOvhORojw0VpGo6LNKQicSslfjhmLDlUpCgV0J@ojxV@rTbjaNJdWkKnTEhNarw/UOe1TRHhnoBUsTmqPUyQc9sj2vYY9t126uv94@i/MYhYW77mbQHcVym5nA@LmooIbNh9GXgukgV67juO4lMmrZsuM6FLC/9iaNENEp3vKizwO2pCyExCWyA4HhnZdNrlCRg1NqYotUGIhqojSDHdzX0w2GgyEIRuRoScYOzNznzuP/zHG7iRZ4HfRA8AIIOvUBsABKOQGfEWfL96AYMR@D2CV44mVq5i4/RoXuYHMZ/P359AFxtJ3du5GYmhvzoZ/Eo9koWDNdf)

Comment: `using std::vector;` could golf two bytes off this.  It costs 18 bytes, but can remove 4 `std::`s, saving 20.

Comment: better yet, `using V=std::vector<float>;` or similar

Answer (score 2):

## Python 2.7, 33 bytes

```
f=lambda m,s,e:all(m.dot(s)==e*s)
```

input: m=matrix, s=scalar, e=eigenvalue. M and s are numpy arrays

Comment: This looks good, but I think you need to include the byte count of `import np` for it to be valid

Comment: You can just import it as `n`. Also, where are `m`, `s`, and `e` coming from? you need to either input them or make a lambda function

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions. This is my first code golf. This one caught my attention, but I don't really know all the rules yet. So it is better now?

Comment: Nice first answer! This is currently invalid because m, s, and e are not defined. However, if you remove the `f=` part and the entire last line, it's a valid anonymous function, and it's shorter.

Comment: Done. What do you mean by not defined?

Comment: Your previous `print(m,s,e)` statement would not have worked because the variables `m`, `s`, and `e` were not yet assigned/defined. Also, you can remove the space after the colon. Also, you can remove the ` as n` part and just use `numpy` later on; since you only use it once, using the full name actually saves a byte.

Comment: Ok, I understand now. Thank you for the suggestions, squeezing every bit :)

Comment: Shouldn't it be `all` instead of `any`? And I think `s` is the vector, not the scalar, unless I'm missing something

Comment: You could do `m.dot(s)`. And I think it should be `all` as well. And I don't think the second set of parens around `e*s` is necessary.

Comment: It would be even shorter to compare string representations. https://tio.run/nexus/python2#jZDPCoMwDIfP@hQ9tiOV/hEHgk/ihHaoIKwqrTv49C7Wue242y/Jx0eSnlTktj2su7eWOAjQlcZl7bTQwExVme4STDq4efILGZ9uXrd@8oRGkpFhJDRNElrXCrgGLhuoJXD1SRpEg0mDxACSwT@0RBo7XJ24hAI0DsQOi@grkIio2NH8S4rDxt@S2IlWdexwPVGeR6c6RaoBxdKElTie/TAupKfx4sx6b1fqGPyWgeEDthc

Comment: @Dennis: Except that NumPy abridges `repr` representations by default for large arrays, and getting around that (for example, with `numpy.set_printoptions`) costs too many bytes.

Comment: Yes, if the multiplication of `m` and `s` is not equal to `e*s` but some of the numbers on same positions are same, then `any()` wouldnt work I guess. Hence I put back `.all()`.

Comment: I think you can get rid of 4 bytes by removing an extra space and using `all()` rather than `.all()`: `f=lambda m,s,e:all(np.dot(m,s)==e*s)`, you're still using `np.dot()` rather than `numpy.dot()` so it's actually only -1 byte to get it working: `f=lambda m,s,e:all(numpy.dot(m,s)==e*s)`

Comment: Trivial improvement: use `m.dot(s)` instead of `numpy.dot(m,s)`, and get rid of the `import numpy` entirely. On Python 3, you can use `m@s` to reduce things further.

Answer (score 2):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), <s>96</s> 70 bytes

No builtins for matrix-vector or scalar-vector multiplication!

```python
lambda A,L,v:all(L*y==sum(i*j for i,j in zip(x,v))for x,y in zip(A,v))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/python3#jZC9DoIwFEZneIo7FvM1ocVoQsLgzhs0DKiQ1CAaQQO@PN6Wn9mJ5uTklH5TnTXl/Xwt6YQcn7RsGpHvxizr3ndhdzeqHy@yuJFt6WufYsAnihwbMK7s5NjUV11/Kbuqo4xMGAhjNGQCqQoYBam3U4K4KEAmgeITSEX4R1esMyKpF1/hgISd2Nkc4uCBjdmNvbvf1HjuyaXiydzVy28cF1fufVVvKc2f9U49M0/CInRDuOcjj9wY2wRpGDxftu1FLfysPM8P)

-26 bytes by using `zip` thanks to @LeakyNun!

Comment: Try to use zip: [`f=lambda A,L,v:all(L*y==sum(i*j for i,j in zip(x,v))for x,y in zip(A,v))`](https://tio.run/nexus/python3#jZC9DoIwFEZneIo7FvM1ocVoQsLgzhs0DKiQ1CAaQQO@PN6Wn9mJ5uTklH5TnTXl/Xwt6YQcn7RsGpHvxizr3ndhdzeqHy@yuJFt6WufYsAnihwbMK7s5NjUV11/Kbuqo4xMGAhjNGQCqQoYBam3U4K4KEAmgeITSEX4R1esMyKpF1/hgISd2Nkc4uCBjdmNvbvf1HjuyaXiydzVy28cF1fufVVvKc2f9U49M0/CInRDuOcjj9wY2wRpGDxftu1FLfysPM8P)

Answer (score 2):

## Julia, 17 bytes

```julia
(a,b,c)->a*b==b*c
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/julia5#S7P9r5Gok6STrKlrl6iVZGubpJX8v6AoM69EI00j2khB11hB19BawVBB1wjGMFYwiNWJNgayrUEsQ03N/wA)

Answer (score 1):

## R, <s>30</s> 25 bytes

```
s=pryr::f(all(a%*%v==λ*v))
```

Anonymous function, fairly straightforward. Returns `TRUE` or `FALSE`.

Answer (score 1):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 11 bytes

```
vy²*O})²³*Q
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/05ab1e#@19WeWiTln@t5qFNhzZrBf7/Hx1tpKNrrKNrGKsTbaijawRnGesYxMZyRRvrGAIZXIYA)

```
vy²*O})     # Vectorized product-sum.
       ²³*  # Vector * scalar.
          Q # Equivalence.
```

Answer (score 0):

## oK, 12 bytes

```
{y~z%+/y*+x}
```

This is a function, it takes in `[matrix;vector;scalar]`.

This does not work in k for the same reasons that `3.0~3` gives `0` as a result.

---

The following works in **k**, with **14 bytes**:

```
{(y*z)~+/y*+x}
```

Answer (score 0):

## Python, 26 bytes

```python
lambda a,b,c:c*b==a.dot(b)
```

`a` and `b` are numpy arrays, `c` is an integer.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/python2#jZBBCoMwEEXXeopZJmUiSRQLgiexLhKtIDQq0S48vR1jbbvs7s/8x2OY3k2jX2B4ummNOyjhtj2Ms60BgxabornYsjRJOy7M8q0bPTCHM9459AOwOIpYVWkUKQpVY6VQ6E9KUdaUUlQUUHH8h1ZE00boE1eYY0qF3GEZfDkRAZU7mn1JedjEWxI2waqPG64nKrLg1KdI16h5HPGC6sn3wwIdCy9JjPdmZY7j7zhzesD2Ag)

Comment: Are the parens around `c*b` actually necessary?

Comment: @xnor thanks, fixed.

Comment: This only works for small arrays, since NumPy abridges large array string representations.

Comment: @user2357112 example? I'm not sure what you mean.

Comment: If `c*b` has more than 1000 elements, NumPy will replace most of the elements with `...`. [Demo.](http://ideone.com/fTYOTX)

Comment: @user2357112 fixed.

Comment: `==` doesn't work like you're thinking for NumPy arrays. Here, it will produce a vector of elementwise comparison results.

Comment: @user2357112 it returns `[True, True, True]`, which is a truthy value. It's a valid result.

Comment: @Riker: It's not actually truthy; a list looking like that would be truthy, but the result is a NumPy array, and it will outright throw a TypeError if you try to interpret it as a boolean. Also, even if it were a list, it would then be truthy regardless of whether the input was a valid eigenpair.

Comment: @user2357112 I've gotten confirmation from OP that the method of output was acceptable, and that the list will be shorter than 1k (so my original answer also works).

Comment: [Related scoring meta post](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/10085/34718)

Answer (score 0):

## Axiom, 27 bytes

```
f(a,b,c)==(a*b=c*b)@Boolean
```

exercises

```
(17) -> m:=matrix[[2,-3,-1],[1,-2,-1],[1,-3,0] ]; v:=matrix[[3],[1],[0]];
(18) -> f(m,v,1)
   (18)  true

(19) -> m:=matrix[[2,-3,-1],[1,-2,-1],[1,-3,0] ]; v:=matrix[[1],[1],[1]];
(20) -> f(m,v,-2)
   (20)  true

(21) -> m:=matrix[[1,6,3],[0,-2,0],[3,6,1] ]; v:=matrix[[1],[0],[1]];
(22) -> f(m,v,4)
   (22)  true

(23) -> m:=matrix[[1,0,-1],[-1,1,1],[1,0,0] ]; v:=matrix[[2],[1],[0]];
(24) -> f(m,v,7)
   (24)  false

(25) -> m:=matrix[[-4,3],[2,1] ]; v:=matrix[[1],[2]];
(26) -> f(m,v,2)
   (26)  true

(27) -> f(2,1,2)
   (27)  true
```

Comment: I haven't seen this language before, nice answer! What does the `@Boolean` do?

Comment: (a=b)@Boolean would mean "choose among allowed =operator(type1,type2) the one its result is Boolean"; in few words "a=b" has to be Boolean

Answer (score 0):

### Clojure, 60 bytes

```
#(=(set(map(fn[a v](apply -(* v %3)(map * a %2)))% %2))#{0})
```

This checks that all deltas are zero, thus collapsing into the set of zero. Calling example:

```
(def f #(=(set(map(fn[a v](apply -(* v %3)(map * a %2)))% %2))#{0}))
(f [[1 6 3][0 -2 0][3 6 1]] [1 0 1] 4)
```